# Android library set versions of local dependencies on release

Tags: android, maven, gradle-dependencies

Short version:
Module A and B are modules of my Android library.
While releasing module A which depends on module B. How do I set the version of module B in the release process?

I developed an Android library using Kotlin with multiple modules with some of them depending on each other. I am using JFrog Artifactory for hosting and its gradle plugin for publishing of the library modules.
To generate a valid POM, I'm generating it manually in the publish closure of the modules build.gradle. While receiving all dependencies of the module when integrating it in a different project, i fail to set the version of local dependencies.

Code I use to set local dependency:

```
implementation project(path: ':core')
implementation project(path: ':auth')
```

Code I use to generate the POM

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options {
        failOnError false
        encoding "UTF-8"
        charSet "UTF-8"
        addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    }
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.name == 'release') {
            variant.javaCompileProvider.configure{
                owner.classpath += variant.javaCompiler.classpath
            }
        }
    }
    exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html', '**/index.html'
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    archiveClassifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    archiveClassifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId POM_GROUP_ID
            artifactId POM_ARTIFACT_ID
            version POM_VERSION
            description POM_DESCRIPTION

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
            artifact androidJavadocsJar
            artifact sourcesJar

            pom.withXml {
                final dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                ext.addDependency = { Dependency dep, String scope ->
                    if (dep.group == null || dep.version == null || dep.name == null || dep.name == "unspecified")
                        return // ignore invalid dependencies
                    if (dep.group == "MyDevGroup") // I am skipping my local dependencies on other modules
                        return // ignore invalid dependencies

                    final dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('scope', scope)

                    if (!dep.transitive) {
                        // If this dependency is transitive, we should force exclude all its dependencies them from the POM
                        final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                        exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', '*')
                        exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', '*')
                    } else if (!dep.properties.excludeRules.empty) {
                        // Otherwise add specified exclude rules
                        final exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                        dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule rule ->
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group ?: '*')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                        }
                    }
                }

                // List all "compile" dependencies (for old Gradle)
                configurations.compile.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "compile") }
                // List all "api" dependencies (for new Gradle) as "compile" dependencies
                configurations.api.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "compile") }
                // List all "implementation" dependencies (for new Gradle) as "runtime" dependencies
                configurations.implementation.getDependencies().each { dep -> addDependency(dep, "runtime") }
            }

        }
    }
}
```